# KML not loaded on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have 15 KMZ files in an web app. I use google map to load these KMZ into maps. everything is just fine, untill then i add two more KMZ files, the layer is now not showing on the map.

when i look into console in my chrome, i get

```
400 (Bad Request)
```

from http://mt1.googleapis.com/. but, when i try to remove one of KMZs the layers is showing again.

does this mean my app hit the limit? FYI, KMZ file size is about 750kb each.

Comment: [400 error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) means _"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax"_  It's more likely to be a problem with that one KMZ file you're removing.  If you removed all the others and just left that one in, does the problem resolve itself?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the number of KmlLayers you can add to a map.  That limit is based on the total length of all URLs passed to the KMLLayer class:

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport):

> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. If you exceed this limit, none of your layers will display. The limit is based on the total length of all URLs passed to the KMLLayer class, and consequently will vary by application; on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20 layers without hitting the limit.